# play framework 2 securesocial login form - email registration process

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, scala-2.10, securesocial

I'm currently using securesocial out of the box where the registration 
process is

- submit email
- respond to email verification
- enter user details, name etc and automatic login after submitting user 
  details
- next time login with user name

But my users would prefer a more streamlined two step process

- submit user details, name, email, etc. (don't use captcha)
- respond to email verification and login automatically
- next time login with email (I can use withUserNameSupport=false for 
  this)

The password reset/change process is great and won't change.

Can secure social do this?
Are there any examples I can use?

Thanks
Peter

Using scala 2.10, Play 2.2.2, secure social 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

The module only has the sign up flow you are using.

In versions 2.1.x changing the default flows is not that easy as the controllers were objects and you could not remove the default routes without getting errors.  You can add your own controllers with the custom flow though.

Using master (what will become 3.0) you can disable the module routes as needed and add your own or extend the default controllers (since they are traits now) and change things more easily.